# Excel macro replace cell in A by other cell in B

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a excel document where I have something like this

```
     A    B     C
1   1   45    a
2   2   32    b    
3   3   34    H
4   3   37    
5   4   49    i
5   5   76    H
```

Note that 3c is combined but 3b isn't.
I need to do a macro to change the content of B with the content of C but only those that don't have a letter H. so the document would look like this

```
     A    B     C
1   1    a    a
2   2    b    b    
3   3   34    H
4   3   37    
5   4    i       i
5   5   76    H
```

[Here a image](https://imgur.com/a/pJ0Xe)

Comment: If i understand correctly, cell in column A should be replaced with cell in column B if B contains any other value other than H?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: 98 and 56 in cell A3 is merged.. i guess so..  @pnuts

Comment: I edit the post

Comment: Here a image http://imgur.com/a/pJ0Xe

Answer (score 0):

Just use this simple formula in column C,

`=IF(B1="H",A1,B1)`

and drag it throughout the range. Once done, copy paste all of the data in column C to A (paste special)

Comment: A 0 will appear in c4 cause of b3 b4 aren't merged but c4  c3 are merged

Comment: @KevinLamaque add one more outer `IF` to blank out the 0 in that case

Comment: I tried something like `=IF(C1<>0, C)` but still getting 0 or false

Comment: @KevinLamaque try something like this , `=IF(C1<>0, C,"")`

Comment: Oh that work but when i use paste special I choose values and skip blanks and still paste the cell in blank